# what is speaker_wav in tts_to_file

Tags: generative-art, text-to-speech

what is `speaker_wav` in tts_to_file.

```
import torch
from TTS.api import TTS

# Get device
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"

# List available TTS models
print(TTS().list_models())

# Init TTS
tts = TTS("tts_models/multilingual/multi-dataset/xtts_v2").to(device)

# Run TTS
# ❗ Since this model is multi-lingual voice cloning model, we must set the target speaker_wav and language
# Text to speech list of amplitude values as output
wav = tts.tts(text="Hello world!", speaker_wav="my/cloning/audio.wav", language="en")
# Text to speech to a file
tts.tts_to_file(text="Hello world!", speaker_wav="my/cloning/audio.wav", language="en", file_path="output.wav")
```

Answer (score 2):

`speaker_wav` is a reference speech file for the voice one intends to imitate during speech generation.